# Reverse proxying a Websocket upstream with Cloudflare

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I am wanting to use cloudflare on my main website and then use `nginx` to reverse proxy a directory to my `websocket` gameserver.

**NGINX server block**:

```
    location /Fonzy/ {
                    proxy_pass http://websocket;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }
```

---

**Upstream block**:

```
upstream websocket {
        least_conn;
        server GAMESERVERIPHERE:9300;
    }
```

My question is, since the cloudflare site will be a different server than my gameserver, will the upstream still work? Or does the upstream block server have to be a local address?

The reason why I am curious is because I am wanting the "protection" from cloudflare, but still want to have my gameserver hidden (or should I say reverse proxied).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently CloudFlare only allows websocket traffic at the enterprise level. For other plan levels it'll currently be blocked. Eventually websockets will be allowed for all plan levels (likely later this year).

In general, I'd recommend contacting CloudFlare's support team directly. They'd be able to provide the same answer quickly.

Comment: Oh really? I did not know that, wow at the enterprise level? That seems excessive for the price.  Thank you for that information, I will need to refactor this design then.